# Image of an analytic function which is both open and closed.

Tags: complex-analysis

An example of an analytic function, mapping an open set to a closed disconnected set. My hunch is that there’s no such function. Since analytic functions are open mappings, their image will be both open and closed, if such a function exists and the image being both open and closed, has to be the whole plane or empty and hence is connected. Am I correct? Please correct me if I’m wrong. Thank you.

Comment: It is *not* true that analytic functions are open mappings. What is true is that *non-constant* analytic functions *whose domain is connected* are open mappings (in the context of Complex Analysis).

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Then do we have an analytic function which maps an open set to a closed disconnected set? Could you please give one example? Thank you.

Comment: Sure:$$\begin{array}{rccc}f\colon&\mathbb C\setminus\mathbb R&\longrightarrow&\mathbb C\\&z&\mapsto&\frac{\operatorname{Im}z}{\lvert\operatorname{Im}z\rvert}.\end{array}$$The function $f$ is analytic (since it is locally constant) and $f(\mathbb C\setminus\mathbb R)=\{1,-1\}$, which is closed and disconnected.

Comment: Could I say a function which is 1 on the open unit disk and 2 on 2< |z|<3, has image {1,2} which is closed and disconnected? Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: I have posted my example as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take, for instance,$$\begin{array}{rccc}f\colon&\mathbb C\setminus\mathbb R&\longrightarrow&\mathbb C\\&z&\mapsto&\frac{\operatorname{Im}z}{\lvert\operatorname{Im}z\rvert}.\end{array}$$It is an analytic function (since it is locally constant), and $f(\mathbb C\setminus\mathbb R)=\{1,-1\}$, which is closed and disconnected.

Comment: Thank you for the elegant example.